# Basic walking script input

Tags: input, unity-game-engine, lag, topdown

I have this basic script in my game for navigating my character around a top down level, but every time I press any of the keys, there's a slight input lag and the screen freezes for just a second.

I'm not sure how to fix it. If anyone had any ideas, I'd appreciate it.

```js
var walkSpeed: float = 7.0;

function Start () {

}

function Update () {

    rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;

    if(Input.GetKey("w")) transform.Translate(Vector3(0, 0, 1) * Time.deltaTime * walkSpeed);
    if(Input.GetKey("s")) transform.Translate(Vector3(0, 0, -1) * Time.deltaTime * walkSpeed);
    if(Input.GetKey("a")) transform.Translate(Vector3(-1, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * walkSpeed);
    if(Input.GetKey("d")) transform.Translate(Vector3(1, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * walkSpeed);
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in this script that stands out to me as being the cause of any form of lag. Are you sure it's caused by this script?

Comment: Oh really? I have a decent enough pc so i doubt its being caused by that, i also get the same problem on the pc in college, im not really sure what the problem could be, not to worry, thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the character controller that comes with the standard assets. It takes care off all fps movements out of the box.